# Cloudformation Root stack references

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to send the variables from the root stack down to the children, then let each child stack create each resource by using cross stack references?

I'm trying to use a **root stack** to pass down some variables to the **child stacks** like `stackName`, then each **child stack** will use the `stackName` to create its own resource (e.g. API Gateway, DynamoDB, etc.).

==> The goal is to create a whole app from a **root stack**, with each resource (which is created by a **child stack**) has the same prefix like `this-app-`, then for a resource like DynamoDB, the table name will be `this-app-dynamodb-table`. So if it's code, it'd be something like this:

```
function main(stackName) {
  createRoles(stackName);
  createAPIGateway(stackName);
  createDynamoDB(stackName);
}
function createRoles(appName) {
  let roleARN = `${appName}ARN`;
  // create some roles
}
// more functions
main('this-app'); // call the root-stack or the main function, pass in the name of the app as a parameter.
```

From AWS Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html), it seems like the **root stack** still has all the `Resources`  and use `"Fn::ImportValue`.

From [this guide about nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html), it looks like if I just want to reference to another stack, I'll have to save the stack in an S3 bucket then use:

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
  "Properties" : {
      "NotificationARNs" : [ String, ... ],
      "Parameters" : {Key : Value, ...},
      "Tags" : [ Tag, ... ],
      "TemplateURL" : String,
      "TimeoutInMinutes" : Integer
    }
}
```

I've looked at some answers online but they don't solve the problem, or maybe I'm looking at the problem from a wrong angle.

> Update 15 May

I've added the templates to an S3 bucket.

There's one thing I don't understand:

If the child stack looks like a normal one, how does it take the variable? I thought it should look like this:

```
 "Resources": {
        "RootStack": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Properties" : {
                "TemplateURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/RootStack.json",
                "DynamoDBTableName": { 
                    "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "RootStack", "TableName" ]
                }
            }
        },
        "DDBTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Properties": {
                "TableName": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "RootStack", "DynamoDBTableName" ]
                },
                "AttributeDefinitions": [...
```

and the RootStack.json should look like this:

```
"Resources": {
        "Database": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Properties": {
                "Parameters": {
                    "TableName": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-dynamodb-table"
                    }
                },
                "TemplateURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/DatabaseStack.json.json"
            }
        }
    },...
```

Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Have you had a look at nested stacks? You have one parent stack, and that parent stack can kick off multiple child stacks - passing down variables from the parent to the child.

Comment: Yes. The second link included above is about working with nested stack. I can't make it work because it seems like the root stack still has all the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass down the parameters from the parent stack like this:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "NestedStack Example",
  "Parameters" : {
    "MyParameter1" : {
      "Type" : "String"
    },
    "MyParameter2" : {
      "Type" : "String"
    },
    "MyParameter3" : {
      "Type" : "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "ChildStack1": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
          "My1stParemeter": { "Ref": "MyParameter1" },
          "My2ndParemeter": { "Ref": "MyParameter2"}
        },
        "TemplateURL": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template-bucket/mytemplate1.json"
      }
    },
    "ChildStack2": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
        "Properties": {
          "Parameters": {
            "My3rdParemeter": { "Ref": "MyParameter3" }
          },
          "TemplateURL": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template-bucket/mytemplate2.json"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

You can also pass down attributes from resources created in your parent stack to child stacks. For example if you created an instance in your parent stack called `myinstance` then you could have this in your nested stack resource:

```
"ChildStack1": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
          "MyEC2PrivateIP": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "myinstance", "PrivateIp" ] }
        },
        "TemplateURL": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/template-bucket/mytemplate1.json"
      }
```

Your child cloudformation template would look like a normal template, nothing special to do there - you just need to have the parameters you are "pulling" in from the parent listed as parameters as per normal.

Comment: Thank you @Warren, let me try what you suggested.

Comment: I'm trying your approach and I have these problems: I have to keep replacing the `.json` files in the bucket if I need to apply any changes. Also, I might need to create a bucket policy other than public read (even I don't store any credentials in my template). Is there an easier way using `Fn::ImportValue` from stacks in the same folder so I can run create-stack against one root-stack json file?